# How do i output my data in xslt table properly?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

[so this is how i want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8WB5.jpg)
I'm a relative newbie at xml/xsl, please explain any mistakes nicely (:

This is a small snippet from xml file:

```
<weather yyyymmdd="20200616">
<year>2020</year>   
<month>06</month>
<date>16</date>
<dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek> 
<overall>Considerable clouds</overall>
<overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
<highest>30</highest>
<lowest>25</lowest>
```

and here is my xslt so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/forecast">
<html> 
<body>
    <h1><xsl:value-of select="@qLocation" /> [<xsl:value-of select="@qTime" />]</h1>

    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="orange">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="weather">
            <xsl:sort select="@yyyymmdd" order="ascending" />
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="orange" align="center">
            <xsl:value-of select="date" />.<xsl:value-of select="month" />
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="overall" /></td>
        </tr>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

right now, my output for <xsl:value-of select="overall"> all shows up under the monday column, rather than at the right date/ day spot. I cant seem to find any help on this. Please advice!
also, will need help with changing the month displayed from 06 to Jun.

Comment: Please show a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context. P.S. If your input always starts with a Monday, this will be easy. Otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Your input has only one day in it, so it is output in the first column. If your input was this

```
<forecast>
    <weather yyyymmdd="20200516">
        <year>2020</year>   
        <month>06</month>
        <date>16</date>
        <dayOfWeek>Mon</dayOfWeek> 
        <overall>Monday  clouds</overall>
        <overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
        <highest>30</highest>
        <lowest>25</lowest>
    </weather>
    <weather yyyymmdd="20200616">
        <year>2020</year>   
        <month>06</month>
        <date>16</date>
        <dayOfWeek>Tue</dayOfWeek> 
        <overall>Considerable clouds</overall>
        <overallCode>cloudy</overallCode>
        <highest>30</highest>
        <lowest>25</lowest>
    </weather>
</forecast>
```

-You get output in two columns.

Is your input guaranteed to have a record for every day of the week? If it does, then you are OK.

If not, you will have to check which days of the week you have and only create a column for only those days.

Alternatively, you can create columns for all days of the week, then for each week you slot the day into the appropriate column. To show how to do this, I would need to see at least a week's worth of XML. eg is the <forecast> element for a week, or some other period of time?